# Angular2 dynamically attaching DOM events

Tags: angular, typescript, dom-events

I'm working with Angular2 and devextreme for angular2. I am trying to add some functionality from a question on their site which calls for an event handler to be attached to the html element

```
    $('html').on('dxclick', function(event) {
        console.log('DxClick - Clicked');
    });
```

Obviously being in angular2 this would be frowned upon, so I am trying to work out how to do it properly. I've tried the following:

```
constructor(@Inject(EventManager) private eventManager: EventManager) {
    this.eventManager.addGlobalEventListener('html', 'dxclick', function(event: any) {
        console.log('DxClick Clicked');
    });
}
```

This just causes and "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" exception

```
public ngAfterViewInit() {
    let htmlElement: any = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    while (htmlElement && htmlElement.localName !== 'html') {
        htmlElement = htmlElement.parentNode;
    }

    if (htmlElement) {
        this.eventManager.addEventListener(htmlElement, 'dxclick', function (event: any) {
            console.log('DxClick Clicked');
        });
    }
}
```

This code finds the html element and the addEventListener is executed successfully, however the callback function is never executed.

Is it possible to reproduce the jQuery code, and if so what have I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to the global events within your components with the following syntax, e.g. resize event:

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
resizeWindow() {
    // window has been resized
}
```

Comment: This also causes and "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" exception. I think html is not a valid target for the HostListener